# Parsing an array posted to nodejs server using querystring

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, query-string

I always use querystring to parse data posted by client. But this is the first time I am posting an array, and I'm having same issue.

client side:

```
        $.ajax({
        url: 'myurl',
        type: "POST",
        data: {ids: ["str1","str2","str3"]},
        success: function (msg) {
            location.reload();
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            alert("ServerError");
        },
        cache: false,
        });
```

server side:

```
var body='';
   req.on('data', function(chunk) {
    body += chunk.toString();
   });

  req.on('end', function() {
    var parsedbody = querystring.parse(body);
    console.log(parsedbody);// {'ids[]':["str1","str2","str3"]}
```

My problem? Well, first note the comment: the key is `ids[]` intead of simply `ids`. So strange and annoyng. And the big problem: **if I pass an array with one string like this:**

```
 data of ajax request--> data: { ids: ["str1"] }
```

the console.log becomes

```
console.log(parsedbody);// {'ids[]':"str1"}
console.log(parsedbody['ids[]'].length);// 4 (instead of 1)
```

As you can see my array become a string and this is a problem.

Comment: body is a querystring!!

Answer (score 0):

You could just easily create your own wrapper around `querystring.parse()`. Example:

```
var qs = require('querystring');

function parseQS(str) {
  var result = qs.parse(str),
      keys = Object.keys(result);

  for (var i = 0, len = keys.length, key, newKey; i < len; ++i) {
    key = keys[i];
    if (key.slice(-2) === '[]') {
      newKey = key.slice(0, -2);
      if (!Array.isArray(result[key]))
        result[newKey] = [ result[key] ];
      else
        result[newKey] = result[key];
      delete result[key];
    }
  }

  return result;
}

console.dir(parseQS('foo[]=bar&baz=bla&quux[]=123&quux[]=456'));
// outputs:
// { baz: 'bla',
//   foo: [ 'bar' ],
//   quux: [ '123', '456' ] }
```